# How to store 3D Graph (x, y, z) data using SQLAlchemy/Mysql?

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, sqlalchemy, mysql-python

I am using Python with Flask to serve X,Y,Z values of 3D graph to Javascript (Plotly library). Data looks like this:

```
z = [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1];
x = [0.0100,0.0420,0.0500,0.0508,0.0769,0.0883,0.0900,0.1101,0.1256,0.1300,0.1385,0.1607];
y = [0.0131,0.0190,0.0248,0.0250,0.0310,0.0370,0.0384,0.0430,0.0490,0.0530,0.0550,0.0610];
```

All of those are for 1 3D graph and it looks like this:
[image]

Problem is, I will have many 3D graphs on my website and storing all of them in Python arrays in code is ridiculous. What would be most effecient way to store all those coords in database? Thanks.

Comment: you can convert those variable to JSON and convert it to String and store it to your database, But you need to convert it back again when getting the `string` value.

Answer (score 3):

You can use PostgreSql database, it's have ARRAY's, so, you can create a table, what would contain columns:

```
id: integer
graph_name: text
xpoints: double precision[]
ypoints: double precision[]
zpoints: double precision[]
```

Where "double precision[]" is a array of 8-byte floats datatype.

So every graph would be stored in a single row of the table.

For the array columns, you should use [postgresql.ARRAY](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/postgresql.html#sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.ARRAY) datatype (in SqlAlchemy)

Comment: Thank you, I will look at it